# External Displays Post iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, external-display

With iOS 13 the setter for `screen` was deprecated, and there's not much documentation out there that says what the alternative should be. I have looked at other stack overflow posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191134/setter-for-screen-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0) but the code does not function in my app. This is the function I have in my view controller to set up external displays, which works, but warns me that the setter has been deprecated for screen. It is called in the `viewDidLoad()` function of my ViewController.

Variables initialized in my ViewController

```
    // External Display Support
    var secondWindow: UIWindow?
    var secondScreenView: UIView?
```

Function to connect and display to external screen.

```
    @objc func setupScreen() {
        if UIScreen.screens.count > 1 {
            // Find and store the second screen
            let secondScreen = UIScreen.screens[1]
            
            // Create a local variable to store the second window using the screen's dimensions
            let externalWindow = UIWindow(frame: secondScreen.bounds)
            
            // Windows require a root view controller
            let viewController = UIViewController()
            
            // Tell the window which screen to use
            externalWindow.screen = secondScreen // This is where the deprecation error is
            
            // Set the dimensions for the view for the external screen so it fills the screen
            secondScreenView = UIView(frame: externalWindow.frame)
            
            // Add the view to the window
            externalWindow.addSubview(secondScreenView)
            
            // Unhinde the window
            externalWindow.isHidden = false
            
            // Configure the View
            let hostingController = HostingControllerPresentable(rootView: DefaultPresentationView(appIcon: Bundle.main.icon ?? UIImage()))
            
            viewController.addChild(hostingController)
            viewController.view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
            hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (viewController.view.topAnchor)),
                hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (viewController.view.bottomAnchor)),
                hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (viewController.view.leadingAnchor)),
                hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (viewController.view.trailingAnchor)),
            ])
            
            hostingController.didMove(toParent: externalWindow.rootViewController)
            secondWindow = externalWindow
            externalWindow.rootViewController = viewController
        }
    }
```

What replaces this setter, and how do I need to update the code for this to work?

Comment: Have you adopted the scene delegate in your app? If so then you assign the external screen to the `screen` property of the relevant `UIWindowScene`.  If you haven't adopted the scene delegate approach then use the code you have and ignore the deprecation warning

Comment: We have not adopted scene delegate. We'll have to look into adopting that then. Thank you for the clarification and the information!