# Airplay - External monitor support with SwiftUI in iOS 14

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, ios14

Xcode 12 no longer generates projects with an AppDelegate, and so all the guides out there on streaming your app to an external display no longer work.

Now we have `WindowGroup` to play with.

I can't figure out how to get Airplay working with this new approach.

I've looked at [Implementing external monitor support in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58033818/2114482) but that uses delegate methods that aren't available.

Is this even possible at the moment?

Comment: You can still elect to use a UIkit application lifecycle in new projects even with SwiftUI

Comment: Looking into this now as an alternative

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same issue.  Just want to airplay and broadcast a custom SwiftUI View to the TV/display.

Comment: Yup! Searching for screenDidConnect brings up an article written around the same time. https://prathamesh.xyz/blog/2020/10/7/add-multi-screen-support-to-swiftui-apps The main takeaway is that you need to listen for UIScreen.didConnectNotification.

Comment: I've updated with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you need to listen for `UIScreen.didConnectNotification` and then make changes to UIWindow.

This is how I solved it.

You need to listen for the connect/disconnect notifications. These are triggered when a user does the whole screen share thing.

In have the following listeners on my root View inside `WindowGroup` in the main `App` file:

```
.onReceive(screenDidConnectPublisher, perform: screenDidConnect)
.onReceive(screenDidDisconnectPublisher, perform: screenDidDisconnect)
```

Here are the publishers:

```
private var screenDidConnectPublisher: AnyPublisher<UIScreen, Never> {
  NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: UIScreen.didConnectNotification)
    .compactMap { $0.object as? UIScreen }
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
    
private var screenDidDisconnectPublisher: AnyPublisher<UIScreen, Never> {
  NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: UIScreen.didDisconnectNotification)
    .compactMap { $0.object as? UIScreen }
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

The final parts are the functions that you run when the notification is received:

```
private func screenDidConnect(_ screen: UIScreen) {
   let window = UIWindow(frame: screen.bounds)

   window.windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .first { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.screen == screen }
            as? UIWindowScene

   let view = ExternalView().environmentObject(externalDisplayContent)
   let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
   window.rootViewController = controller
   window.isHidden = false
   additionalWindows.append(window)
        
   externalDisplayContent.isShowingOnExternalDisplay = true
}
    
private func screenDidDisconnect(_ screen: UIScreen) {
   additionalWindows.removeAll { $0.screen == screen }
   externalDisplayContent.isShowingOnExternalDisplay = false
}
```

`externalDisplayContent` is just a custom struct I created that passes along the information I want to display on the `ExternalView`, which is just a regular SwiftUI view.

You can see that the content gets passed through as an environment object, but it doesn't have to. You can use an initialiser on the view instead if you prefer.

I think you may also get away with passing through bindings.